# How to use jSoup to grab text from <pre> field and keep formatting

Tags: html, awk, jsoup

I'm trying to simplify a log created by a ruby script which makes a simple log file which consists of a mixture of timestamp message and JSON, similar to this:

```
[TIMESTAMP] MESSAGE
[
    {
        "JSON STUFF HERE"
    }
]
[TIMESTAMP]
```

The problem is if you save the log file as .txt it has no line breaks, which makes it nigh impossible to regex out. In fact, the only time line breaks are preserved are in a browser html version, where the text is wrapped with the "pre" tag. I've tried awk with gsub as:

```
gsub( / \[/, /\r\n\[/)
```

but still can't get it to create line breaks in the file. I was wondering what the easiest way would be to load it formatted as I need to automate the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will be enough to get you started.

You can think about it another way with awk.  Awk is designed to work on "records".  While the typical record separator is a newline, the record separator can be set to any useful single char with standard awk or a regex with GNU awk.

So if your log file was like:

```
[TIMESTAMP] MESSAGE : Some message [ { "JSON STUFF HERE" } ] [TIMESTAMP] MESSAGE2 : Some other message [TIMESTAMP] ...
```

where it has matching brackets, but no newlines, you could try an awk like:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\]|:"; RS="\["} NF==3 && !/\{/ {print $1, $2, $3}' data
```

where

- The field separator is set to `FS` is set to `]` or `:` in the `BEGIN` block
- The record separator `RS` is set to `[` in the `BEGIN` block instead of using the default of newlines
- If there's a message delimiter like `:` as in your comments, the`NF==3` is a simple, but not great, test for printing `TIMESTAMPS` and `MESSAGES` as fields `$1` and `$2`.  `$3` is assumed to be the rest of the record.
- Because valid `JSON` can contain those same field separators, there's also a test for the '{' to exclude short `JSON` blocks.

The example data as a single line leads to:

```
TIMESTAMP  MESSAGE   Some message 
TIMESTAMP  MESSAGE2   Some other message
```

Now obviously, the pattern tests are weak, considering data past the `MESSAGES` could have more `:` or `]` leading to a higher `NF` count in those records.  In that case, ensuring that `$1` matches a certain timestamp format would provide a better record catch.

Comment: I ended up doing similar with sed, which in the end looked like: `sed ':again;$!N;$!b again; :b; s/{[^{}]*}//g; t b' FILENAME | sed '/,$/d'` This is by far the best answer and pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few separate problems in this question, and I'd say that having no newlines (in the JSON part) actually makes the regex process *easier* (definitely with `sed`), but maybe I've misunderstood here.

So that said, assuming you have python available, you can use its [json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to do pretty-printing for JSON at least:

```
python -mjson.tool logfile.json
```

See the docs for options around indentation and newlines especially.

Comment: I guess to clarify, I actually don't need the JSON, it's clutter for me. I just need the time stamps with their messages. And the log file is not a json file, its a .log file, since its JSON objects thrown around inside of timestamps for GET requests and such.

Comment: OK, I see. So why don't you just grep for lines matching the format of `[TIMESTAMP] message`, in the (safe enough) assumption that the JSON lines will never match that...

Comment: I've used awk to grab them, but only when formatted with the line breaks, with:  `/\[.*\] DEBUG : |\[.*\] WARNING :|\[.*\] ERROR :|\[.*\]   ANY :|\[.*\]  INFO :/` The problem is I can't get it with line breaks except by copying and pasting from the html, which isn't automatable. Using an HTML parser gives me one long space delimited string.